# Vertex Array Objcects - glGenVertexArrays GL_INVALID_OPERATION on OSX

Tags: macos, opengl, swift, opengl-3

I'm trying to get a simple OpenGL program going, but I can't get it to display anything.  I'm using Swift on a Mac, neither of which I am familiar with, although I've got a good amount of experience with OpenGL on windows.  The program runs fine (no GL errors or anything), but nothing displays, until I add this at the end of my openGL initialization:

```
var vao:GLuint=0;checkGlError();
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);checkGlError();
glBindVertexArray(vao);checkGlError();
```

Then, it gives GL_INVALID_OPERATION as soon as I call glGenVertexArrays(), however the docs don't mention that as an option.

I worried that I might not have a GL3 context (and really I'd prefer to just have a GL1/2 context, however the Swift headers seem to be missing things like glBegin() and glColor3f(), so I decided to settle for GL3), so I tried to manually request one:

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder);
    let attribs=[NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile,NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core,0];
    pixelFormat=NSOpenGLPixelFormat(attributes: UnsafePointer<NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute>(attribs));
    openGLContext=NSOpenGLContext(format: pixelFormat, shareContext: nil);
    openGLContext.view=self;
    openGLContext.makeCurrentContext();
};
```

However this didn't seem to affect things at all.

Comment: Incidentally, if you are missing prototypes for things like `glBegin (...)`, you should add `#include <OpenGL/gl.h>` to your code. It sounds like only `<OpenGL/gl3.h>` is being included, and *that* header does not include functions from legacy OpenGL. This whole `OpenGL/...` business is Apple-specific, so wrap that in something like `#ifdef __APPLE__` ... `#endif`.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman this is Swift not Obj-C, so I cannot use #includes

Answer (score 5):

First, `glBegin (...)` is not valid in a core profile context. You are going to need a legacy (non-core) context for that.

Now, since the legacy context is limited to OpenGL 2.1, it only offers [`GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/APPLE/vertex_array_object.txt). In a 2.1 context, you can call `glGenVertexArraysAPPLE (...)` and `glBindVertexArrayAPPLE (...)` and they will do the same thing.

The problem you are encountering is that on OS X, you link to the same framework regardless which context version you get. That means that you can call functions that are not supported by your context at run-time. Any time you try to use a GL 3.2+ function from the legacy context, you get `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by creating a bridging header and including #include  in that, then using a GL1 context.